# Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, ruby-on-rails-3.1, libreadline

I am working on a rails app.
Installed Postgresql using postgresql-9.1.2-1-osx.dmg
Installed pg gem.
Then when I executed `rake db:create`
getting the following error -

> dlopen(/Users/sathishvc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@knome-vivacious/gems/pg-0.12.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib

Checked if `/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib` exists or not. It does not.
So, it should be existing somewhere else in the system or I do not know, if I need to install any other piece of software for this.

Advice anyone please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time after I posted this question, I found that `libpq.5.4.dylib` resides in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/`.
So, I created the following link:
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 sathishvc  admin       43 Jan 28 23:40 /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib`.

This solved the problem then.

Comment: In OS 10.15.7,I can't use ```chown username libpq.5.4.dylib```.The ownuser is ```root```,I cant't change it.How did you do that?

Answer (score 406):

if you have upgraded

- PostgreSQL with homebrew (brew update && brew upgrade),
- macOS (eg. from Catalina to BigSur)

then simply uninstall the pg gem:

```
gem uninstall pg
bundle install
```

and the path will be corrected for you. No need to uninstall the whole PostgreSQL cluster.

Comment: `brew update && brew upgrade` worked for me, I did not even need to uninstall and reinstall pg.

Comment: If it wasn't `pg` you could get rid of all of your gems with `gem uninstall --all` then install bundler and then run bundle install to install everything again (given you have a Gemfile)

Comment: @ianstarz why would one want to do such a massive thing? ;-)

Comment: If you tried the things above and still get this error, `brew link libpq --force` fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: gem uninstall pg and bundle install worked for me!

Comment: this should be the correct answer imho

Comment: I've tried a few of the answers provided here on an M1 machine and this was the only one that worked. Thank you.

Comment: I had this problem after home-brew upgraded my installation of PG 14. The instructions above `gem uninstall pg` followed by `bundle install` worked for me.

Comment: After the `brew upgrade` path to `.dylib` is changed, it can't find them. gem `uninstall pg` and `bundle install` solves the problem.

Answer (score 135):

I'm on OSX Monterey (M2-chipset) and had a similar issue. Running (mind the version) helped:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

brew update, brew link --force, brew uninstall && brew install,.. all did not.

Comment: I had to do the same thing in Monterey on the update to 14.5. But I didn't use `sudo`

Comment: This answer is golden I installed Ventura beta and got this after a brew update and brew upgrade

Comment: In case of using Apple Silicon based Macs, you should use this command to create symlink: `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Comment: This is likely due to `brew` renaming `postgres` to `postgres@14`.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me on Apple M1 Pro, Monterrey 12.0.1

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the gem (@awenkhh's answer)? That fixed it for me. I find that strongly preferable over manual symlink management!

Comment: Another grateful commenter. Glad this ten-year-old post is useful again.

Comment: It is better not to add links to a different directory (`usr/local` in the the answer). The problem is with the extra `postgresql@14` at the end after the `lib` in the path. The following helped me: `cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/lib/` and then run `ln -s postgresql@14/* .` . This will ensure all libraries are available under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/lib/` which is where they are expected to be in the first place!

Answer (score 84):

Try to run

```
bundle pristine pg
```

and that was it. you find solution here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/109644

Comment: This worked for me on Rails 7, MacOs Monterey

Comment: This worked for me on Rails 6.1, MacOs Monterey

Comment: Worked like a charm for me Rails 6.1.5, Ruby 2.7.1, MBP M1 MacOS Monterey (thank you! )

Comment: I tried some solutions and they didn't work.
This one worked for me. Rails v6.1.7

Comment: Works for me with ruby 2.6.5 and rails 5.2.4. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me after run ```brew update & brew upgrade```

Comment: Worked for me. Remove cmd had still retained this problem, but pristine cleaned it up to point to the new postgres version.

Answer (score 39):

For me (MacOS Monterey) the file eventually turned up under: `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib`

So to fix the initial error first create the directory it is looking for and then create a symlink to the existing file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: This is exactly what fixed it for me.  I noticed yesterday when trying to use postgis for the first time, that for some reason my postgresql folder also had the @14 and it was causing postgis not to work correctly in my Java app.  Today I went back to work on this rails app and got this error, I'm thinking this might fix both.

Comment: Thanks! This save my day (Monterey, Intel)

Comment: This one worked.

Comment: In my case I had to do this
```sh
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Answer (score 14):

---

I followed something similar to [S.D.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73526869/5535747) on a M1 chip. Linking to `/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib` as suggested by Patryk Szczepański didn't work for me so I created an empty `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib` and sym-linked

```
mkdir /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql
mkdir /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.14.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Chip Apple M1 Pro

---

Comment: you da real MVP!

Comment: Thank you! Banging my head for a while on this!

Answer (score 14):

this worked for me in MacOS Monterey

First I created the directory it is looking for and then created a symlink to the existing file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: I'm also on Intel Mac (Monterey), and this works: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.14.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib`

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this issue after switching over to the PostgresApp and removing the existing PostgreSQL version via

```
brew remove postgres
```

I ultimately solved the problem by re-installing PostgreSQL via

```
brew install postgres
```

I was able to retain the use of the PostgresApp by adding the following to my .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

You can also try running:

```
brew doctor
```

As it alerted me to this as well as some additional errors.

This error was also affecting my ability to use the Paperclip gem as it was causing ImageMagick to fail with the same error.

(Using OS X 10.8.2)

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue whilst configuring postgresql as my default database for django on my Mackintosh.

It was resolved after installing psycopg2-binary via pip.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

I hope this works for someone out there

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer works

Comment: If it fails to create symlink for `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib` be sure that directories exists by running `sudo mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib`... then retry

Answer (score 6):

For me the following worked:

```bash
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/* /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/
```

Comment: Worked for me! I did have postgresql@14 installed via Homebrew and macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same issue after upgrading to a new ruby version (2.7 to 3.1.2) in my Rails 7 application. In my case, I had to uninstall and reinstall the pg gem in my Rails app:

```
gem uninstall pg
bundle install # (which installed the pg gem with native extensions)
```

This solved the issue for me. Hope this helps anyone who is facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is uninstalling pg gem:

`gem uninstall pg`

and running

`bundle install`

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, uninstalling /reinstalling gem didn't help. But I added the PostgreSQL library path to `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If you also have MySQL installed, this line can look like:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Of course pay attention to version number in the PostgreSQL path, at the time of this writing it is 9.3. 
I'm using RVM, Ruby 2.0.0, pg gem 0.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 3):

*this is not a direct answer to the question but can arise frequently*

Two additional cases that might be of interest if you have upgraded PostgreSQL with homebrew:

1. you have proceeded in the past to some pruning of gem versions
2. your application is older and cannot take a recent version of pg (I have a rails 2 app failing with pg 0.17 and nearly killing the server: the mkmr.log increases exponentially ...try 200GB! )

you may actually have numerous versions of pg to rely upon

when you run

```
gem uninstall pg
```

if you have more than one version, the system will ask which version you wish to delete. But that list may be useful to you! As an alternative to awenkhh's answer you may stop there and reset your gems to an acceptable version

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue on Ventura. It happened after I upgraded my posgresql version from 9.6 to 12.

I tried to symlink by using following command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/lib/postgresql@12/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

If this is not helping, try:

```
brew link postgresql@12 --force
```

It created 377 symlinks. Here is the entire output of the above command:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.15_2... 377 symlinks created.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Installed postgresql@14 via homebrew

Then:

`mkdir /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/`

`mkdir /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib`

`sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.14.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Worked after :)

Answer (score 2):

I kept getting the following error on M1 Mac with Django Running Postgres installed with Homebrew.

```
...
Error loading psycopg2 module:
...
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file),
```

This is how I fixed it
Create a directory where the code is trying to look for the library

```
mkdir /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/
```

Create a symlink to where the library actually exists

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/
```

If these does not work for you, then make sure you identify where the library is located and where the code is trying to look for it and replace accordingly

Run the command

```
locate libpq.5.dylib
```

This will list the dirs where the library is actually located.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to upgrade psycopg2-binar package to the latest version (2.9.5 in my case). Fixed the missing file issue

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew prune` and then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Postgresql 13.4 installed via the EDB installer and Postgis installed via Stackbuilder. None of the solutions worked for me so I just

1. Installed postgresql and postgis via brew
2. Replace the raster2pgsql file (save it in another folder just in case) in /Library/PostgreSQL/13/lib with the raster2pgsql from the postgis brew version

Not sure how it affects other files in the postgresql and postgis EDB version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with posgresql installed with brew. When I run `brew doctor` I found this:

`` Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib ``

Running `brew cleanup` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Error

I was getting this when I tried to start the rails server:

```
rails server
/Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require': dlopen(/Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: <C859835A-2D0F-3B4A-BFAB-2AD961F6197B> /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache) - /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg_ext.bundle
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:49:in `block in <module:PG>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:37:in `block in <module:PG>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:42:in `<module:PG>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:6:in `<main>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler.rb:188:in `require'
    from /Users/st/rails/checkeasy/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

#### Solution

The solution was really easy: uninstall and reinstall the `pg` (postgres) ruby gem for that rails app:

```bash
gem uninstall pg
```

then reinstall it

```bash
bundle install
```

now `rails server` works!