# Libssl and libcrypto causing dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, psycopg2, libssl

I recently uninstalled postgresql and installed pyscopg2 via pip.

I know there's some trickery involved with libcrypto and libssl

Currently i have them symlinked to:

```
$ ls -lah libssl.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   402K Aug 28 11:06 libssl.0.9.7.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   589K Aug 28 11:06 libssl.0.9.8.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    55B Nov 29 23:38 libssl.1.0.0.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    55B Nov 30 02:25 libssl.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

/usr/lib
$ ls -lah libcrypto.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   2.1M Aug 28 11:06 libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   2.6M Aug 28 11:06 libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1.6M Oct 31 22:12 libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    58B Nov 30 02:27 libcrypto.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

whereby I installed openssl via ports

Now when I run arc diff, I am getting the infamous

```
$ arc diff
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

There are a few answers here in SO which talks about symlinking these libs to the postgresql install directory. Obviously, this won't work for me.

What should I do?

Comment: What's `arc`? Also, I see `/usr/bin/php`; that doesn't look very Python to me. And if you *un*installed postgresql, I'm not so sure that `pip` will install postgresql for you if you install `psycopg2` (though, if it doesn't, it should probably fail). Do you have a libpq (any) on your system?

Comment: Related?: [Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib while running rake db:create](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9023482/456814).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib was absent but /usr/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib was not.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case, the library was in /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib. To solve the issue, I ran `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: other way around for for me..! sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib

Comment: For macos big sur i do symlink for /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Answer (score 14):

just use the below commands in your terminal
(use the proper postgresql version)
`$ brew unlink postgresql@14`

`$ brew link libpq --force`

https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded/issues/152#issuecomment-954348544

Comment: This did work for me but then another project broke because it needed `postgresql@14` linked. Instead I reinstalled all my python project modules including psycopg2 by setting `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libpq/lib"` first.

Answer (score 12):

I got the error

> Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib'

> Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)

when running a Django project and to fix it I had to uninstall the pip packages:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2 
pip uninstall psycopg2-binary
```

and then install them again:

```
pip install psycopg2 
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

And this made the project run without the error.

Comment: Using the `--no-cache-dir` option for pip solved this for me.

Answer (score 3):

Not unlike @Pablo Marambio, I fixed this issue by adding the following line to `~/.profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For Postgres.app v9.3.5.0 (presumably others too) I added the following line instead:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then, of course, run `source ~/.profile`

Comment: I like this exporting environment variable better than copying or symlinking libraries on my system.

Comment: This breaks running "psql DBNAME" in the command line for me.  Running Postgres.app v9.5.0.0 and the error returned says "dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart"

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this, I had to uninstall postgresql and then install again.

```
$ brew uninstall postgresql

$ brew update

$ brew install postgres
```

Comment: This solution was almost mine too but in addition, since I'm using a specific version of postgresql, I also needed a `brew link`:
`$ brew uninstall postgresql@11 && brew update && brew install postgresql@11 && brew link --force postgresql@11`

Comment: It is not working for me

Comment: brew link --force postgresql@11 did the magic here

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for postgresql 14 + brew

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using poetry so to solve it on my fastapi project, I had to do this to fix it:

```
poetry remove psycopg2
poetry add psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

It try to load `libpq.5.dylib` from the symlink `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib` but found not file, so you need to update it:

```bash
# TODO: get this from the error, after "Library not loaded:"
SYMLINK_PATH="/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib"

# TODO: find this in your machine. The version maybe different than mine
DESTINATION_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib"

sudo mv $SYMLINK_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH.old
sudo ln -s $DESTINATION_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH
```