# Issue with connecting Postgresql with flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin-4

While I was trying to connect my flask app with postgresql I was getting the following error which says I don't have the libpq.5 the error log as follows

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/Desktop/Projects/pgflask/main.py", line 3, in 
> app = create_app()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/Desktop/Projects/pgflask/Mautourco/**init**.py", line 10, in create_app
> db.init_app(app)
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 326, in init_app
> engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 614, in _make_engine
> return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 804, in engine_from_config
> return create_engine(url, **options)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "", line 2, in create_engine
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 283, in warned
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 601, in create_engine
> dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 669, in import_dbapi
> import psycopg2
> File "/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 51, in 
> from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libpq.5.dylib'
> Referenced from: '/Users/noelsjacob/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgflask-3P3nCHJ0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so'
> Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file

Comment: please post the code as well

Comment: How did you install `psycopg2`? Have you activated the virtualenv you are trying to run this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libpq.5.dylib` library is a part of the PostgreSQL database, it needs to be installed on your system before you can use `psycopg2` to connect to the database.

First, make sure that PostgreSQL is installed on your system.
If you're using Mac, you can install it using Homebrew:

```bash
brew install postgresql
```

In case PostgreSQL is already installed on your machine, it might be that `libpq.5.dylib` library is not in your system's library path. So make sure `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is set:

```bash
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/<version>/lib/postgresql/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: still, I'm facing the issue after adding the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH any other solutions

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643452/libssl-and-libcrypto-causing-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-lib-libpq-5-dylib