# rbenv, homebrew, and postgres9.3: pg upgrade form 9.2 broke pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew, rbenv

### Problem

I'm having a hard time getting Postgres working on my system after upgrading to 9.3 with homebrew. I naively ran `$ brew cleanup` so I don't have 9.2 to troubleshoot with. This is the error I get when I run `rake db:create`

`dlopen(/Users/<USERNAME>/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/<USERNAME>/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/<USERNAME>/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle`

`$ brew doctor` says everything is fine. I've also gone ahead and re-installed postgres (didn't have anything I needed to keep on my home machine), and still hasn't changed the error message.

#### Related SO Questions & other links

- [Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib while running rake db:create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023482/library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpq-5-4-dylib-while-running-rake-dbcreate)
- [Upgrading PostgreSQL 9.2 to 9.3 with Homebrew](http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/09/postgresql-93-brew-upgrade/)

Comment: can you output
 >brew doctor

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from your second link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering my own question...

Didn't read the info closely enough (fyi: `brew info <formula>`), needed to run:

`$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

Comment: Small world!  Thanks for saving me some time, Chris!