# Connecting to PostgreSQL database using Python not possible after brew upgrade

Tags: python, postgresql, homebrew, psycopg2

I recently upgraded brew and part of it was an update to PostgreSQL. The update was successful, brew suggested to move older files to a different folder (I don't remember the exact line right now).

Now when I try to connect to the DB using python `psycopg2` package, I get the following error messages:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/fabioteichmann/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/fabioteichmann/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

I tried reinstalling Postgres through brew but no success. I can connect to the DB using different tools.

Anyone able to help me out?

PS: apparently the library files are in a different place:

```
'/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib'
```

How can I adapt to that?

Comment: You should probably [start using virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#sidestep-dependency-conflicts).

Comment: I am already using one.

Comment: Take a look at [Homebrew error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894232/error-loading-psycopg2-module-library-not-loaded-libpq-5-dylib). In particular second comment to answer.

Comment: From what I gather this is due to a change in packaging as shown in this [discussion/bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3579) which relates to this [Postgres versioning](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/107726).

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer thanks to @Adrian Klaver:

I created a symlink through:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

*From [this discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3579)*

This does the job for me (for other PostgrSQL version you need to adapt the link a bit)

Answer (score 0):

It tried to load `libpq.5.dylib` from the symlink `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` but could not find the file, so you need to update it:

```bash
# TODO: get this from the error, after "Library not loaded:"
SYMLINK_PATH="/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib"

# TODO: find this in your machine. The version maybe different than mine
DESTINATION_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib"

sudo mv $SYMLINK_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH.old
sudo ln -s $DESTINATION_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH
```