# How do I get libpq to be found by ctypes find_library?

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, apple-m1, psycopg3

I am building a simple DB interface in Python (3.9.9) and I am using psycopg (3.0.7) to connect to my Postgres (14.1) database. Until recently, the development of this app took place on Linux, but now I am using macOS Monterey on an M1 Mac mini. This seems to be causing some troubles with ctypes, which psycopg uses extensively. The error I am getting is the following:

```
ImportError: no pq wrapper available.
Attempts made:
- couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
- couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
- couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
```

Based on the [source code of psycopg](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/blob/956238bef739675d46d6e65c953c1dcef10a165e/psycopg3/psycopg3/pq/_pq_ctypes.py#L16-L21), this is an error of ctypes not being able to util.find_library libpq.dylib. Postgres is installed as Postgres.app, meaning that libpq.dylib's path is

/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin/lib

I have tried adding this to PATH, but it did not work. I then created a symlink to the path in /usr/local/lib, but (unsurprisingly) it also did not work. I then did some digging and found [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue44689) describing the same problem. I am not a big macOS expert, so I am unsure on how to interpret some of the points raised. Do I need to add the path to the shared cache? Also, I do not want to fork the Python repo and implement the dlopen() method as suggested, as it seems to lead to other problems.

Anyhow, is there a solution to quickly bypass this problem? As an additional reference, the code producing the above error is just:

```
import psycopg

print(psycopg.__version__)
```

Comment: You can try installing `pip install "psycopg[binary]"` for bin packages. Otherwise potentially this lib just doesn't support m1. Possibly related [issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/162).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just checked and according to psycopg3's documentation, ```pip install "psycopg[binary]"``` is not supported by M1 Macs (https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem but the solution was suggested to me by [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516579): try setting envar `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path you identified.

NB, to get it working myself, I:

- used the path `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib` and
- had to install Python 3.9

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by running:

```
pip uninstall psycopg
pip install "psycopg[c]"
```

This provides a [local installation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html#local-installation) of psycopg3 which is needed since there are no binaries available for M1 macs. I installed `postgresql` (and `libpg`) via  homebrew, running `pg_config` gives me a proper output.

Using the pure python package and setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has solved itself by using psycopg2 instead of psycopg3, so it seems to be a problem of the latter. It would be still good to know why so as to solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**A new way**

This issue came up on my Windows laptop using Jupyter, although with WSL and Ubuntu it was fine...it was even fine using IntelliJ that was using python from Windows. I have a Mac Mini so I thought I'd test what I used instead **pg8000**

Now, pg8000 is a pure python implementation to connect to Postgresql. After a brew install of Postgres (and a few shenanigans with PSQL to get it working), this worked fine `pip3 install pg8000`

**Basic Recipie**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pg8000 as pg

def db_conn():
    conn = pg.Connection(host='localhost', 
                         database='dev_database', 
                         user='postgres', 
                         password='yourPassword!')
    return conn

# Now you have a connection, query your data with a cursor

conn = db_conn()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tab1')
data = cur.fetchall()

# Now 'data' contains your data, or use the new way with conn.run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Grabbing data from tab1...')

    for row in conn.run('SELECT * FROM tab1'):
        print(row)

    conn.close()
```

It all seems pretty much the same as using psycopg, but the new method `connection.run` is pretty good too!